# Why PFX's public key is different when sign pdf document?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, public-key, pfx

Using a certificate that I created, I signed a PDF document with the iTextSharp library.

When, in the pdf signature panel, I will see the public signature I have the following information in hexa

[image: pdf public key]

But, when I get the public key from the same certificate through my code in c#

```
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\mycert.pfx", "pass");
    byte[] publicKey = certificate.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
```

The result in decimal (converted to Hexa) is different.

e.g. In the byte array 5 is 130 - 82 in Hexa, but in pdf, the 6th key is 0D in hexa

[image: pdf public key]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks and Sorry for my english.

Comment: Did my answer clear up the issue?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the cause for the discrepancy is concerned, your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56515629/1729265); the answer explains:

> The difference is that Adobe presents the hex dump of the complete `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object (the public key including the algorithm information and the key value) while your code only dumps the `RSAPublicKey` (the key itself).
>
> ...

For more details read there.

You actually can recognize the plain public key in the Adobe Reader output, it starts at the end of the first line,

> [...] 30 82 02
>
> 0A 02 82 02 01 00 FA 8B ...

---

The solution is slightly different, though, as the code in that question is in Java.

Your code uses the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` class `X509Certificate2`. [As far as I can see](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2) this class does not expose the whole `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` by itself. Thus you should use a different class here.

An obvious choice would be BouncyCastle classes, either `X509CertificateStructure` or `X509CertificateHolder`, depending on the BouncyCastle version you use (an older version of BouncyCastle is included in iTextSharp, newer ones can be retrieved from their web site). These classes expose the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`.